# Oracle APEX. Не могу выключить автотранзакцию autocommit в сессии oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Здравствуйте. Прошу вас помочь. У меня APEX 5.0. А аккаунт админа себе позволить не могу так как я регистрировал свою базу данных не на своём локальном сервере , а на сайте apex.oracle.com . Я ввёл эту команду в поле ввода sql commands:

```
set autocommit off
```

Но сразу ошибка втёрлась:

ORA-00922: missing or invalid option .

Как же мне тогда выполнить эту команду(остановить автотранзакцию) , а то я незнаю , что мне делать (так как не имею прав админа , но может быть даже не имея их я могу чтото сделать просто подскажите что) ?  Срочно нужно.

Comment: попробуйте [вот так](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598235/disable-auto-commit-in-oracle-application-express). Ответ был дан в апреле 2013, но может быть еще актуальным. PS сам я APEX не пользуюсь, поэтому проверить не могу...

Comment: Но у меня нету чекбокса autocommit , как в том примере в том то и дело ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для доступа к настройкам необходим доступ администратора см. доку http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39151/adm_login.htm#AEADM168

как только будет туда доступ необходимо воспользоваться этим, чтобы включить настройку (Enable Transactional SQL Commands) см доку http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39151/adm_wrkspc002.htm#AEADM390

ps. на apex.oracle.com нет доступа к админке, так что там облом )

Comment: Спасибо. ))) Я подозревал , что эта системная команда с автотранзакцией , которую может запустить юзер с правами администратора